# Advantages of Konva.js over Paper.js

Tags: javascript, paperjs, konvajs

So I've been looking for a canvas wrapper to work with, and it seems as though I've narrowed down the options to `Konva` and `Paper.js`.

`Konva` seems to have a really active maintainer, can render individual layers one at a time (more performant) and great documentation. `Paper.js` on the other hand, has a broader feature set and handy extras like convert to svg and drag/drop functionality.

I'd be using the wrapper to generate quilting patterns. Pretty simple 2D geometry, with an emphasis on being able to mix and match different colors and shapes. No animation required. Would really rather go with SVG, but I know that with the amount of shapes I'll be rendering, it might be more performant with canvas.

With that in mind, what would the advantages of going with Konva over Paper? Has anyone had experience using both?

Comment: There is only one way to find the best library - make small prototype with every library and see what works better for you.

Comment: AFAIK PaperJS is the only JS graphics library that has a robust implementation of [Boolean Operations between Paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_operations_on_polygons). I don't know if you need that kind of functionality, but if you do it is something difficult to pull off all by yourself.

Comment: I've been using konva in a project and it's really useful. I like it. Konva gives a view architecture with all functionality includes groups, layers, mouseevents, zindex etc,